# Windows 10 times out trying to open old IDE HDD for browsing

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

I demoed an IDE HDD caddy at a PC store before buying, and Windows 10 at the store displayed the contents of the IDE HDD fine (files and folders).

When I bring home the IDE caddy, after connecting to my PC (Win10 Pro 64-bit), the 4 partitions are visible in file explorer, but if I try to open any of the partition drives in file explorer, the address bar will display the green flashing right 'in progress', but nothing else happens.

Originally an anti malware service was running @ ~60% CPU, but that has now subsided.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Do you have other devices that can read the drive? What Windows build number are you using?

Comment: Hi @user1574981, yes, another Windows 10 64-bit laptop can read the contents of the 4 partitions, and displays the partition drive names too. The first Win10 desktop is Version: 1703, OS Build: 15063.608

Comment: Are the ports the same on both computers (USB2/3) ?

Comment: @harrymc, USB3 on the original desktop, USB2 on the laptop.

Comment: That might be the reason for the difference.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Plugging the drive into a USB2 port at the back resolved the problem. Add an answer if you like.

Comment: Done as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The poster affirms that plugging the external drive into a USB2 port has fixed
the problem. The drive seems to work badly only when plugged into a USB3 port.

I don't know if that drive is supposed to be certified for USB3,
but evidently it does not work, at least on your computer.

Your options as I see are :

- Continue using it only on USB2.
- If the drive is advertised as compatible USB3,
  try it on USB3 on another computer, to see if the problem is with your
  USB3 port or driver, or if the drive is defective.
- If the drive is defective and is still under warranty,
  then ask for it to be exchanged.